# Unpacking unknown object from within DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Newbie here. I have a dataframe which contains an object I don't recognise, which I need to unpack and convert into a new separate dataframe, to form a new normalised structure.

A simplified version of the df is;

```
   trasaction_id   customer_details
0   1       <customer {id:'A123', name: 'Tina'} as x >
0   2       <customer {id:'B456', name: 'Tony'} as x >
0   3       <customer {id:'C789', name: 'Tim'} as x >

Name: customer_details, dtype: object
```

I can't seem to access the dictionary within the object inside of the angle brackets. I've tried all sorts of things, if I try `print(df['customer_details].__dict__` I get the following: `{'_is_copy': None, '_data': SingleBlockManager`.

I've even tried to do something hacky like this string manipulator, but I'm sure there's something basic I'm missing through being new to this.
`'{' + df['customer_details'].apply(lambda st: st[st.find("{")+1:st.find("}")]) + '}'`

Ultimately what I'm trying to achieve is to unnest these customer_details into a separate df linked by the transaction_id and store it in a simple normalised structure in an RDB. I believe in order to use a standard tool like json.dumps() etc I want it to look like this (with each element double quoted);

```
    transaction_id   customer_details
0    1        {id:'A123', name: 'Tina'}
0    2        {id:'B456', name: 'Tony'}
0    3        {id:'C789', name: 'Tim'}
```

This is driving me mad. Thanks for your help!

Comment: if it is object with properties `id` and `name` then how about `{'id': st.id, 'name': st.name}`. But if it is only normal string then you would have to cut off values from string using string functions or regex.

Comment: more detailed: `df['customer_details'] = df['customer_details'].apply(lambda st: {'id': st.id, 'name': st.name})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have object/class with properties `id` and `name` so you can try to get

```
{'id': st.id, 'name': st.name}
```

which means

```
df['customer_details'] = df['customer_details'].apply(lambda x: {'id': x.id, 'name': x.name})
```

or directly to separated columns

```
df['id']   = df['customer_details'].apply(lambda x: x.id)
df['name'] = df['customer_details'].apply(lambda x: x.name)
```

---

Example code:

```
import pandas as pd

class customer:
    def __init__(self, id_, name):
        self.id = id_
        self.name = name
    def __str__(self):
        return '<customer {{id: {}, name: {}}} as x>'.format(self.id, self.name)

data = {
    'trasaction_id': [1,2,3],
    'customer_details': [
        customer('A123', 'Tina'),
        customer('B456', 'Tony'),
        customer('C789', 'Tim')
    ],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# ---

df['id'] = df['customer_details'].apply(lambda x: x.id)
df['name'] = df['customer_details'].apply(lambda x: x.name)
print(df)

df['customer_details'] = df['customer_details'].apply(lambda x: {'id': x.id, 'name': x.name})
print(df)

#new_df = pd.DataFrame( df['customer_details'].to_list() )
```

Result:

```
   trasaction_id                        customer_details
0              1  <customer {id: A123, name: Tina} as x>
1              2  <customer {id: B456, name: Tony} as x>
2              3   <customer {id: C789, name: Tim} as x>

   trasaction_id                        customer_details    id  name
0              1  <customer {id: A123, name: Tina} as x>  A123  Tina
1              2  <customer {id: B456, name: Tony} as x>  B456  Tony
2              3   <customer {id: C789, name: Tim} as x>  C789   Tim

   trasaction_id                customer_details    id  name
0              1  {'id': 'A123', 'name': 'Tina'}  A123  Tina
1              2  {'id': 'B456', 'name': 'Tony'}  B456  Tony
2              3   {'id': 'C789', 'name': 'Tim'}  C789   Tim
```

---

**EDIT:** If you have strings then you can use `regex` to get values from string

```
import pandas as pd
import re

data = {
    'trasaction_id': [1,2,3],
    'customer_details': [
        "<customer {id:'A123', name: 'Tina'} as x >",
        "<customer {id:'B456', name: 'Tony'} as x >",
        "<customer {id:'C789', name: 'Tim'} as x >",
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# ---

df['id'] = df['customer_details'].apply(lambda x: re.search("id:'(.*)',", x)[1])
df['name'] = df['customer_details'].apply(lambda x: re.search("name: '(.*)'}", x)[1])
print(df)

def myfunc(x):
    r = re.search("id:'(.*)', name: '(.*)'}", x)
    return {'id': r[1], 'name': r[2]}

df['customer_details'] = df['customer_details'].apply(myfunc)
print(df)

#new_df = pd.DataFrame( df['customer_details'].to_list() )
```

Comment: Thanks @furas - I tried `df['customer_details'] = df['customer_details'].apply(lambda x: {'id': x.id, 'name': x.name})` but was told the attribute was a string and given the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'`

Comment: if you have string then you will have to get values from string using `re`. I added example with strings.

Comment: I've tried applying myfunc and now I'm getting the following: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: it seems in some place you have empty cell - `None` instead of string. OR string has different elements and it can't find pattern `"id:'(.*)', name: '(.*)'}"` and it may need different pattern.